# Is there a name to describe a video game player who plays for aesthetics?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Word to describe a video game player who plays for aesthetics or other useless-in-game achievements? I'd go with overachiever but it doesn't sound like internet slang, nor is it very concise.

Related on Arcade: [Collector gamer, or player gamer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/179264/collector-gamer-or-player-game)

Comment: Does it have to be a video-game player or just anyone who is doing things (or playing a game) for aesthetics? This is a bit of a narrow question, and is probably best answered, well, exactly where it was, on gamers.SE. Try searching urban dictionary to see if there's some latter-day slang for this.

Comment: This does not sound like a single type of gamer. It is a bit of both "explorer" and "achiever" type.

Comment: Is there a 'flaunter' type? Where are you getting these 'types' from?

Comment: It is from Bartle types. There is also a DGD1 model that fills the gaps between Bartle types and explains the types that can be in between. Source: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/6474/personality_and_play_styles_a_.php?print=1

Comment: To be fair, most things you can achieve while playing most games are useless. Unless you count entertainment as a use, and then you can apply that to pretty much any achievement in any game.

Comment: Some achievements offer in-game advantages while others are purely aesthetic.

Comment: Definitely not "overachiever", that means something else entirely (that they perform better than you'd expect). What springs to my mind (from the "aesthetics" thing) is the distinction between someone who "plays for fun" and someone who "plays to win".

Comment: Maybe a *showoff*?

Comment: Bartel types looks like an acceptable answer if worded properly. With seemingly no definitive non-opinionated answer applicable here, these links were very insightful. @ermanen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**The Four Bartle Types**](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/6474/personality_and_play_styles_a_.php?print=1)

> This model, which was based on observing and analyzing the behaviors people playing together in a multi-user game, holds that there are four different kinds of play style interests, each of which is given a descriptive name: Killers, Achievers, Explorers, and Socializers.

- **Killers**: interfere with the functioning of the game world or the play experience of other players
- **Achievers**: accumulate status tokens by beating the rules-based challenges of the game world
- **Explorers**: discover the systems governing the operation of the game world
- **Socializers**: form relationships with other players by telling stories within the game world

There is also a DGD1 model [and the *Keirsey Temperaments*] that fills the gaps between Bartle types and explains the types that can be in between. -ermanen

The OP's case most closely matches *Achiever*. The linked article goes *much* more in depth about this.

Answer (score 6):

The word that springs to mind for me is "completionist."  I initially began using the word in reference to MMO (Massively Multi-player Online) gamers who sought to collect every "achievement."

I have since heard the word used to describe gamers who desire 100% completion of any particular aspect of a game.  Examples range from in game achievements, to clothing, quests, or 100% completion status.

Wiktionary defines the word as follows:

> [Completionist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/completionist) - one who insists on completion.

This urban dictionary listing from 2010 more closely matches the usage I am familiar with as a native North American English speaker and online gamer:

> [Completionist](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Completionist)
>   - Someone who, when playing a video game, has to collect all of a certain item, or complete something in the game 100%.
>
> "Only a completionist would collect all of the flags in Assassin's
>   Creed."

Comment: Do the flags do something?

Comment: The use of *completionist*, as far as I can tell, seems to be restricted to gamer subculture.  But the similar word *completist*, meaning "one who wants to make something complete, such as a collection" is mainstream, though somewhat uncommon, and apppears in published dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

A ***trophy hunter*** (or *trophy gamer*): "*achievement unlocked!*".

Of course, in 30 years, when fine arts colleges start minting Masters of Fine Gaming, this kind of activity will be called "*performance art*" :)

Answer (score 2):

While not limited to gaming, the term *[grandstander](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/grandstander)*. *Grandstand* is defined as

> (US, informal) to try to gain the applause or admiration of an audience by or as by making an unnecessarily showy play (grandstand play), as in baseball [*Collins*]

Alternatively, you could say *[exhibitionist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/exhibitionist)*

> A person who behaves in an extravagant way in order to attract attention: [*Oxford Dictionary Online*]

Comment: +1 for *exhibitionist*, especially as it pertains to gaming-as-art (and for the tinge of voyeurism).